# How to properly use typescript union types with different internals

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

In the below example I receive a typescript error even though the error can never actually come happen in the code. I am either passing Category1 or Category2 into the function, therefore when returning the `ComputedCategory` type it IS going to have the same value under both the `computed` and `name` property, however typescript does not recognize this. It thinks the value can be from either union. For instance when setting the name property it throws an error basically saying `{ computed: 'category1', name: 'category2' }` is not assignable to `ComputedCategories`'  First of all why is typescript doing this and why is it not smart enough to realize these values are never possible, second how do i properly write this to express the type? I am hoping the example doesn't use a bunch of type guards with specific returns as that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
type Category1 = {
    testName: 'category1';
    name: 'category1'
};
type Category2 = {
    testName: 'category2';
    name: 'category2'
};
type Categories = Category1 | Category2;

type ComputedCategory1 = {
    computed: 'category1'
    name: 'category1'
};
type ComputedCategory2 = {
    computed: 'category2'
    name: 'category2'
};
type ComputedCategories = ComputedCategory1 | ComputedCategory2;


const computeCategory = (category: Categories): ComputedCategories => ({
    computed: category.testName,
    name: category.name
})

// ERROR
Type '{ computed: "category1" | "category2"; name: "category1" | "category2"; }' is not assignable to type 'ComputedCategories'.
  Type '{ computed: "category1" | "category2"; name: "category1" | "category2"; }' is not assignable to type 'ComputedCategory2'.
    Types of property 'computed' are incompatible.
      Type '"category1" | "category2"' is not assignable to type '"category2"'.
        Type '"category1"' is not assignable to type '"category2"'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is a function overload

```
function computeCategory(category: Category2): ComputedCategories;
function computeCategory(category: Category1): ComputedCategories;
function computeCategory(category: any ): ComputedCategories{ 
 return {
  computed: category.testName,
  name: category.name
}}
```

Here's [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxARigXigbwCgoSpEBnYAOTgFsIAuKAcgGMFl0tmBuY0gHZ1GLdolQZMzQgF8%20oSLA4SQAJlwF%20JCtWFM2yrqt5aoQ%20vrGcMx2fPDR449AEsI5DU%20tYoAHyXONnyECo4otGAArogAJl4q2HhEpFCs4VGxloaS0inmIgaB3HYhDrDp0RBx2WoayaRpEZUxWUW2eXqiNbZypYowFbHxru6eg1XDkn7lTUPdwYQAZpECrMAuKAKp45MgABRWKky7qgCUx%20PVgW7kfMur65vbsxC7BzXHNZjnMxkT2Tc7is1hsto0-m9DlwmHABCAoD8Bi8rtYbvgoMQ0BBgJE0Ft6uDmkwoRgAHQ6Gj0AA0-HyxJqpPyshkhEIhMQb3q2ncugsXSKUhpHT5hW8UlkpzZOxqey5ZB5lIKJLUzCFgk6opUPUl7NeMrlFI1ysFpjp-O82qAA) and the official [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxARigXigbwCgoSpEBnYAOTgFsIAuKAcgGMFl0tmBuY0gHZ1GLdolQZMzQgF8%20oSLA4SQAJlwF%20JCtWFM2yrqt5aoQ%20vrGcMx2fPDR449AEsI5DU%20tYoAHyXONnyECo4otGAArogAJl4q2HhEpFCs4VGxloaS0inmIgaB3HYhDrDp0RBx2WoayaRpEZUxWUW2eXqiNbZypYowFbHxru6eg1XDkn7lTUPdwYQAZpECrMAuKAKp45MgABRWKky7qgCUx%20PVgW7kfMur65vbsxC7BzXHNZjnMxkT2Tc7is1hsto0-m9DlwmHABCAoD8Bi8rtYbvgoMQ0BBgJE0Ft6uDmkwoRgAHQ6Gj0AA0-HyxJqpPyshkhEIhMQb3q2ncugsXSKUhpHT5hW8UlkpzZOxqey5ZB5lIKJLUzCFgk6opUPUl7NeMrlFI1ysFpjp-O82qAA)

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Is this a feature people normally use?

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work in my codebase as it just results to the bottom overload of any with no type safety.

Comment: @C.Johnson it shouldn't allow `any`, have a look at the links I've added. Can you make a playground that reflects your codebase?

Comment: I have made an example jsfiddle with basically what is happening. If you look at the bottom of the page animal.makeSound(randomSound) throws a TS error even though the code will always run. What is the best way to solve this scenario?

https://jsfiddle.net/dpvacyoz/

Comment: I updated the fiddle to represent a truly unknown sound which an overload can't solve for. I basically need the `getAnimalFromSound` to also say that the animal it returns is related to the sound it took in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you trying to achieve exactly. If you want to just "maching types", then in `type`, you need to give the correct type like `string` and not the value like this:

```
  type Category = {
    testName: string;     //incorrect testName:'category1'
    name: string;
  };

  const category: Category = {
    testName: 'category1',
    name: 'category1',
  };

  //here you don't need to give any type to function, ts will handle it
  const computeCategory = (obj: Category) => ({
    computed: obj.testName,
    name: obj.testName,
  });

  console.log(computeCategory(category));
```

Or if you want to be specific about the values then you can use enums like this (with this you can only use values that you write inside `enum`):

```
  enum Category1 {
    testName = 'category1',
    name = 'category1',
  }

  enum Category2 {
    testName = 'category2',
    name = 'category2',
  }

  type Object = {
    testName: Category1.testName | Category2.testName;
    name: Category1.name | Category2.name;
  };

  const computeCategory = (object: Object) => ({
    computed: object.testName,
    name: object.name,
  });

  console.log(computeCategory(Category2));
```

Or simpler way like this:

```
  enum Categories {
    testName1 = 'testName1',
    testName2 = 'testName2',
    testName3 = 'testName3',
    name1 = 'name1',
    name2 = 'name2',
    name3 = 'name3',
  }

  const computeCategory = (category1: Categories, category2: Categories) => ({
    computed: category1,
    name: category2,
  });

  console.log(computeCategory(Categories.testName1, Categories.name1));
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is your `type Object` is not typed the same as `ComputedCategories`. It can have the following when values from either are allowed.

`{ testName: 'category1',  name: 'category2' }`.

 Exactly what I am trying to do is not shown here because it is a lot more complicated, but what I don't understand why typescript is allowing values from both types after to be in the same type. I wasn't sure if I would get an answer as this is rather complicated and seems like a bug but I am not sure how to solve it.